# How do I change the app icon in the 'Recents' Screen?

Tags: android, icons, manifest, android-recents

I know how to change the icon of my app, but when I look at the [Recents Screen](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/recents), the icon is the default one.

App icon (all good so far):

[image]

Icon in my Recents Screen:

[image]

This is the 'application' tag of my 'AndroidManifest.xml'

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/iconout"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/iconout"
    android:logo="@mipmap/iconout"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

I've tried many solutions that I found on this platorm (that didn't work), like:

1. file->new->image asset->choose image..
2. install & unistall the app
3. build & clean project
4. delete all the default icons on my project
5. drag & drop my icon to drawable from mipmap folder

Any other possible solutions? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the solution and decided to answer for anyone that will encounter the same problem in the future.

I fixed it by adding `android:icon="@mipmap/iconout"` in the main `activity` tag declaration in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, like so:

```
<activity
        android:icon="@mipmap/iconout"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And here's the final result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the format of the icon to PNG. That works for me.

Or you could try the application on different devices to see if it's not a problem of the emulator/phone.

Comment: It is actually a png :(