# How do I change Recent screen icon in Ionic Framework?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic-native

Hi I just noticed the icons provided for app is shown properly in the launcher , but when it comes to the **"Recent screen"** I am able to see the android head(default) icon only. Is there a way to change this icon in Ionic framework like modifying config.xml? Help would be much appreciated.

This question answers for android native apps- [How do I change the app icon in the 'Recents' Screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63414916/how-do-i-change-the-app-icon-in-the-recents-screen)
but I want a similar solution for Ionic (web apps)

Comment: Latest Android versions use the Adaptive Icon of an app for the launcher, but in the Recent screen, maybe the legacy icon is used. I'm not sure about it though. Anyway, make sure to package both the Adaptive and the Legacy icons with your app.

Comment: @Reqven any idea on how to configure it in Ionic?